# Untaring Transform Adding Directory Based on Pattern in Filename

Tags: linux, regex, tar

**Background:**

I've got 20 or so tar files at about 25G each containing a few million files. The directory structure for these files is not the format it needs to be so I want to fix that. Because of the sheer volume, the more steps I can complete in one sweep the better.

**What I've Tried:**

What I was hoping to do was a loop over the tar files performing this extraction and transformation:
`tar -xf TX.tar.001 --transform 's,^TX/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*_([0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_.+\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*),\2/\1,'`

However, tar spits out this error which google seems to know very little about:
`Invalid transform replacement: back reference out of range`

**Question:**

Any recommendations either how to convince tar to work with my backreferences or to do this in another way that would be able to complete in a reasonable amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the parentheses around each group:

```
tar -xf TX.tar.001 --transform 's,^TX/\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*_\([0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\)_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]_.+\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*\),\2/\1,'
```